# Which methods help to improve wireless signal strength?

Tags: wireless-networking, signal-strength

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Improve Wireless Signal](https://superuser.com/questions/45960/improve-wireless-signal)
>   [How to extend Wi-Fi signal across rooms?](https://superuser.com/questions/17897/how-to-extend-wi-fi-signal-across-rooms)

I have a [Billion BiPAC 7401VGP R3](http://au.billion.com/product/voip/bipac7401VGPR3.php) VoIP router.  My router sits inside my living room, and there are several blindspots in the house where the WiFi signal is very low.

The worst place is the bedroom - if I were to draw a line from where the router is positioned to the bedroom, the line would go outside the house (through a brick wall) and back inside the house (through another brick wall).

If I take either my laptop or iPhone into the bedroom, the signal runs from medium-low at best to low, which makes it pretty unusable.

I recently purchased a 9dBi antenna to plug into the router in an attempt to alleviate the problem but it doesn't appear to have made any difference.

Some other things of note:

- My cordless phone is XDECT (1.8GHz) so it is unlikely to be interfering.
- I have experimental with the Tx Powerlevel on the router (setting it to maximum) but it makes no difference.
- I have changed the channel on the router, but it makes no difference.

Any ideas about what I could do to improve the situation?  At the frequencies we are dealing with, should the WiFi signal bend around the corners of the inside of my house, or will it always try to go "line of sight" through the brick walls?