# Unable to connect to wifi router

Tags: windows-7, windows, wireless-networking, router, signal-strength

I have a Dlink DIR-524 wifi router. The problem is when I go to another room (this room is next to the room where the router is placed. The room is of normal size not big), I am unable to connect to the wifi at all. What is this problem? Why is this happening and how can I solve it?

Regards

Comment: There's a number of things that could affect this, and @DaveM has given some good suggestions. It is also possible that there is something in the construction of the building, either inside the walls or in the paint/wallpaper, that could be killing your signal. Your best solution will probably end up being to run a wire and set up another AP on the other side.

Comment: Or set up a round-corner reflector.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which methods help to improve wireless signal?](http://superuser.com/questions/45960/which-methods-help-to-improve-wireless-signal), http://superuser.com/questions/17897/how-to-extend-wi-fi-signal-across-rooms

Answer (score 1):

Do a full survey of all rooms using a toolk like [Heatmapper](http://www.ekahau.com/products/heatmapper/overview.html) and assure there are no other wireless devices on the same channel as your router,  You may have to do this several times.  If tou find conflicts, change your channel and set it to that channel.  Do not allow it to automatically select the channel

You can also reorient the router to see if that changes the signal.  Nearby objects can reflect or attenuate the signal and a small move can make a big difference.

You may also be able to get a high gain antenna which would boost the signal. [Dlink](http://www.dlink.com/us/en/business-solutions/wireless/accessories/ant24-0700-indoor-7dbi-directional-patch-11g-antenna) makes one and there are others avaiulble and an online search may yeild many more.

Also make sure you have the latest firmware.

Comment: I am unable to find its firmware update. I have searched Dlink website and it is not listed there

Comment: That would mean you have the latest so nothing to do there.