# Internet amazing via Ethernet, unusable via WI-FI?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, internet, ethernet

so I got this new internet a few days ago, it's a 4G LTE Dongle which I connected to a TP-LINK TLL-MR3420 router to share it with the house (the ISP recommended it), I'm connecting my desktop to it via LAN and I'm getting correct speeds on Speedtest, but I also have a laptop connected to the WI-FI and it's literally unusable from a few rooms out, even when it has 4-5 signal bars, I can't even start up Speedtest, keeps saying timed out.

Both devices running Windows 8.1

Comment: This is pretty standard with wi-fi unfortunately. You could try getting larger aerial/usb extension to move dongle from back of PC/move router to more open area in the house/changing wireless channel to less contended one etc, but you're unlikely to get the the reliability of ethernet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Slow wireless in my room: should I get a faster router or multiple extenders?](http://superuser.com/questions/626914/slow-wireless-in-my-room-should-i-get-a-faster-router-or-multiple-extenders)

Comment: @RJFalconer I understand it is a common thing with WI-FI to be slower, but not to be completely unusable, I'm saying I can't even do a Speedtest, it keeps timing out, yes I'd expect it to be slower, just not to this level, I've never experienced this before, especially when it has 4-5 signal bars.

Comment: Have you tried changing channels?

Comment: @DavidPostill It's set to auto, I'm going to monitor it and change it manually.

Comment: [How to Fix Your Wi-Fi Network: 7 Tips](http://www.pcworld.com/article/260524/how_to_fix_your_wi_fi_network_7_tips.html) is worth a read. It lists some tools you can use to determine the best channel.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of things to look at for this issues:

- Check if your laptop wireless card have the default settings.
- Make sure there is no noise around you "other channels" change your channel and test it again.
- Be sure you have choose the right baud 
  B/G/N.
- If nothing worked check your DHCP service sometimes your router will duplicate the IP, a restart will solve it.

**Last note** I have noticed that win8 or win10 not gives you the right signals bars, keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I had something similar and while you will have some loss and those theoretical speeds sometimes do not represent real world. But saying this there are lots of things you can do.

Try:
As suggested above check it's not your laptop, connect to another wifi network or get closer to the router and see if that improves the speeds or even try a simple tethering of your phone to your laptop via wifi.

If that works it could be that the local area has some interference from our wifi routers. 2.4ghtz is crowded!

Try:
Devolo home plugs - they have some really good products and use a wifi and home plug combos

Try a dual band router, that allows 5ghtz frequency less interference with neighbouring routers etc.

As with everything wifi related so many options....

Good luck keep us posted